System Search AppIntent/AssistantIntent not working in iOS
@available(iOS 18.0, *)
@AssistantIntent(schema: .system.search)
struct SearchIntent: AppIntent {
  static let title: LocalizedStringResource = "Search <app name redacted>"
  static let searchScopes: [StringSearchScope] = [.general]

  @Parameter(title: "Criteria")
  var criteria: StringSearchCriteria

  @MainActor
  func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    MyDependencyManager.shared.performSearch(with: criteria.term)
    return .result()
  }
}

// In AppShortcutProvider

AppShortcut(
  intent: SearchIntent(),
  phrases: [
   "Find \(\.$criteria) in \(.applicationName)",
    "Search for \(\.$criteria) in \(.applicationName)",
  ],
  shortTitle: "Search <app name redacted>",
  systemImageName: "magnifyingglass"
)

The search works when using the Shortcuts app, but not when using Siri. For example if I ask Siri "Search for SOME_THING in MY_APP_NAME" it just does a Google search or prompts me to install the app from the App Store (I am running a debug build via Xcode). I tried a few variations of this phrase none of which worked and I can't get this to work from Spotlight either (not even sure how to trigger it?)
I am using Xcode 16 and running the app on an iPhone 16 Pro with iOS 18.2 beta and Apple Intelligence turned on.
What am I doing wrong here? I cannot find any other information about this intent or how to properly set it up and use it.

I'm not sure this is actually enabled in Siri yet. Yes, the APIs are there but they've been there since 18.0 to allow people to plan for this. FWIW, same for me, I can't get it to work. I don't think it's setup yet.

With 18.2 beta 2, this may actually be testable! Check it out

@orion Thanks for the reminder, I just tested it and Siri now opens my app and navigates to my search screen, but it doesn’t seem to pass the search query to my intent. For some reason the search bar is focused and I can enter some text but the text I passed as part of the query is not entered (that’s what my intent does and then performs the search automatically using it). I’ll have a closer look soon to see if I am doing anything wrong here, but it works fine with the shortcut I mentioned above.

That might have something to do with me adding this to the AppShortcutProvider. After removing it from there, I now see this in the logs: "No ConnectionContext found for 12933943520" and  "Identifier rank 4 should have been less than 4" and it doesn't even launch my intent now.
